# iOS CLLocation property doesn't retain value

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, xcode5, cllocation

I'm trying to save on memory the `self.mapView.userLocation.location` in `CLLocation` property but after I assign the value to the property and I check the value of the property I get this:

`<+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/19/14 4:21:14`

Here is my code:

.h:

`@property (retain, nonatomic) CLLocation *currentlocation;`

on my .m

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    if (self.currentlocation != self.mapView.userLocation.location)
    {
       self.currentlocation = self.mapView.userLocation.location;
    }

}
```

My question is who can I retain the value of self.mapView.userLocation.location on `self.currentlocation` and keep it on memory?

I'll really appreciate you help.

Comment: have you set mapView's `showUserLocation` to true?

Comment: YEs, self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning a pointer to another pointer. So you are actually just storing a reference to the `MKUserLocation`'s location.

It sounds like you want to store the value at that time, not wanting it to change. If so:

```
 self.currentLocation = [self.mapView.userLocation.location copy];
```

Storing a copy should get you what you want.